# Detect if launcher is on foreground

Tags: java, android

I'm using the following code to understand the processes currently on foreground:

```
ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) newContext.getSystemService( Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
List<RunningAppProcessInfo> appProcesses = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
for(RunningAppProcessInfo appProcess : appProcesses){
    if(appProcess.importance == RunningAppProcessInfo.IMPORTANCE_FOREGROUND){
        Log.i("Foreground App", appProcess.processName);
          [...]
    }
}
```

But it works only if I'm using a 4.0.4 launcher like stock one, apex, nova launchrs.
If I switch to GoLauncher or Launcher Pro, they are not logged. It looks like they never go foreground (or this portion of code can't detect them).

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions. This is not a question.

Comment: I'm asking why this doesn't work with < 4.x launchers. What's wrong with the code?